# Publicly inherit from base class, privately inherit from derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

Weird inheritance situation:

```
class Base
{
public:
  public virtual foo() = 0;
};

class A : public Base
{
public:
  public virtual foo() override;
protected:
  int bar;
};

class B : public A//something like 'public Base, protected A'
{
public:
  public virtual foo() override;
};
```

Basically, can B inherit everything from A, but be only "seen" (and only cast-able as) Base. Basically, I want to use a bunch of the functionality of A in B, but want B to be semantically different than A:

```
B b;
Base* valid_ptr = &b;//want this to be ok
A* invalid_ptr = &b;//want this to be invalid
A& invalid_ref = b;//want this to be super invalid
A prevent(b);//want this to not be allowed to happen
```

Comment: Has a instead of is a?  Just springs to mind for this one...

Comment: What happened when you _tried it_?

Comment: Maybe you can pass `A` as a template argument.

Comment: Is `A` supposed to inherit from `Base`? Otherwise the `override` will prevent the code from compiling.

Comment: Inherit `A` privately?

Comment: @ebyrob Yeah I'm thinking the only way to do this is to use an impl pointer...

Comment: @499602D2 Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Praetorian absolutely correct, fixed.

Comment: @KerrekSB that disables being able to cast to the Base interface

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: Yeah, never mind. I had misread the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your code compiles only if A derives from Base. If Base is public for everyone, and A is held protected, the only way is not inherit Base to B across A.

Since A is not visble through B a solution can be

```
class A: public Base 
{ ... };

class B: public Base 
{
   A a;
public:
  ...
};
```

In case the existence of two instance of `Base` into `B` (one as `B`'s base, the other coming with the `a` member) is unacceptable, another way can be to go via virtual bases:

```
class A: 
  public virtual Base 
{ ... };

class B:
  public virtual Base,
  protected A
{ ... };
```

This will make A invisible through B (that cannot convert implicitly into A) but only a single Base to be in common between A and B.

The use of a shared virtual base is a common idiom in all the cases object share partial implementation via member function dominance (the so called "stacked parallelogram imheritance") or via arbitrary number of interface ("diamond object").

OOP purists tend to dislike those figures, but those are proper C++ citizens (even if not finding any representation in other classic OOP inspired languages, due to multiple inheritance missing!)

Comment: Hmmm...good answer, I hadn't considered virtual inheritance because of the overhead of using it.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams I'm not sure what you're referring to, which overhead are you talking about?

Comment: It cost just one pointer... and a double indirection (instead of simple) on virtual calls. Modern compiler sometimes optimize v-tables in the linking process, so the overhead is not that "terrible" as the most of 1990's OOP books tend to recommend. If you plan to use virtual functions, you are in the indirect function call domain. At that point... just use them fully!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're dealing with a [Composition vs Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) problem.

You might have B inherit from Base and use a composition technique to get advantage of A.

Otherwise, for the issue you listed, you might think of rendering the constructor inaccessible:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() {};

};

class B : private A
{
public:
    B() {};
};
```

e.g. (MSVC2012)

> error C2243: 'type cast' : conversion from 'B *' to 'A *' exists, but
>   is inaccessible

Comment: I hadn't thought of over-loaded constructors/casts etc.  That might handle cast-control nicely.  (Not sure about construction of actual useful objects though factory stuff always gets messy for me)

Comment: But what about B and A to both derive from Base ? Wasn't it a requirement?

Comment: If the user is incurring in a **diamond problem** (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) that's another story. In that case composition might be helpful